# React Native (only Android)- Scrollview is being overlap by absolute view

Tags: css, react-native

I'm having a style issue positioning as absolute a view before a ScrollView. On IOS is working correctly, the ScrollView starts after this Absolute View. But on Android, the ScrollView is hiding down the Absolute View.

Which style property am I missing?

Thank you :)

First Android, Second IOS

[image: ANDROID]

[image]

Comment: Check if you have specified height and width else it will affect in android but iOS will be fine

Comment: Height to the scroll view?

Comment: Can you post the code

Answer (score 2):

The style absolute is doing exactly what it is suppose to do, make a view over another. Moreover, if you add a top or a bottom value, the position of the view is related to the whole screen and not the parente view of it. In this case try to avoid use absolute and use flex manipulation like this:

```
<View style={{flex: 1}}> // A view occupying the whole screen
  <View style={{flex: 0.5}} /> // A child view of your header occupying half of the screen 
  <ScrollView style={{flex: 0.5}} /> // Your scrollview occupying half of the screen 
</View>
```

Comment: I need to leave position absolute because I’m making an effect while scrolling. What irritates is that on IOS works perfect but android no

Comment: What effect are you making?

Comment: Parallax effect if the blue part + appears a title

Comment: I understood the effect, but are you trying to scroll the content behind the blue part? like this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryhow_css_parallax_demo.htm

Comment: No the blue part goes up, till half of it’s size

Answer (score 0):

Use `pointerEvents` and set it to `box-none`.

If you do that pointer will not work on the view you entered `box-none`, but the clickable items in that view will work.

Ex:-

```
<View>
 <View pointerEvents='box-none' style={{position: 'absolute'}}> // this is the view that overlaps the scroll view
 <TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>{console.log(`It's Working`)}}> // press on this will work
  <Text>Press ME!!!</Text>
 </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
 <ScrollView/>
</View>
```